Deeper reason for why classical orthogonal polynomials have simple generating functions?
Is there a known reason why all classical families of orthogonal polynomials have simple generating functions? I was wondering whether one could get an explanation using the connection with Sturm-Liouville theory. However, I don't see an immediate way to do this.

Nikiforov and Uvarov, сhapter 5.3.

The reason is that the weight satisfies a simple differential equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula

Got it! Thank you both!
